# jQuery - If statement doesn't trigger on the second iteration of my loop even though it's true?

Tags: jquery, loops, each

The goal is to have the script trigger `$('.actions').find('input[name="update_cart"]').click();` under the condition that the user changes a quantity with a select drop down.  This works as expected.  The problem lies in that I need it to trigger that same function again when the page loads to check to see if the attribute `selected` exists for not, which will work but it doesn't when there is more than one select to test this for.  I've watched the script run and when it seems to loop ok but my if statement will not fire the second iteration.  Very strange.  Any ideas?

An example of the problem page HTML:

```
<div class="quantity_select">
<select name="cart[7d4db75ed7310cccac9772805faa7dcc][qty]" title="Qty" class="qty">
<option value="500" data-qty="500" data-price="0.27" selected="selected">
500&nbsp;envelopes&nbsp;$135.00</option>
<option value="1000" data-qty="1000" data-price="0.18">
1000&nbsp;envelopes&nbsp;$180.00</option>
<option value="2000" data-qty="2000" data-price="0.15">
2000&nbsp;envelopes&nbsp;$300.00</option>
<option value="5000" data-qty="5000" data-price="0.15">
5000&nbsp;envelopes&nbsp;$750.00</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="quantity_select">
<select name="cart[7d4db75ed7310cccac9772805faa7dcc][qty]" title="Qty" class="qty">
<option value="500" data-qty="500" data-price="0.27">
500&nbsp;envelopes&nbsp;$135.00</option>
<option value="1000" data-qty="1000" data-price="0.18">
1000&nbsp;envelopes&nbsp;$180.00</option>
<option value="2000" data-qty="2000" data-price="0.15">
2000&nbsp;envelopes&nbsp;$300.00</option>
<option value="5000" data-qty="5000" data-price="0.15">
5000&nbsp;envelopes&nbsp;$750.00</option>
</select>
</div>
```

My Script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('body').on('change', 'select[name$="[qty]"]', function() {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
                $(that).closest('form').find('input[name="update_cart"]').click();
    }, 300);
    });

    $('.quantity_select').each(function(qsi,qsobj){
        $('.qty').each(function(qi, qobj) {
        if ( !$("option[selected]").length ) {
                $('.actions').find('input[name="update_cart"]').click();
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: I think you're not referencing to the current iterated select element `if ( !$("option[selected]").length ) {` ==> `if ( !$("option[selected]", this).length ) {`

Comment: ^ context is king

Comment: This is it exactly!  Thanks so much :)